# What's the difference between request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] and request.LANGUAGE_CODE

Tags: django, localization, internationalization

What's the difference?

- request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']
- request.LANGUAGE_CODE

or are they the same??

I want to get the browser's language but using request.LANGUAGE_CODE got me to another language.

Answer (score 1):

[**HttpRequest.META:**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META)

The key `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` in the request headers is the language which is acceptable for the response.

From the [docs:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META)

> `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` – Acceptable languages for the response.

[**request.LANGUAGE_CODE:**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-i18n)

Its a string representing the name of the language.

From the [docs:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/#definitions)

> Represents the name of a language. Browsers send the names of the
>   languages they accept in the `Accept-Language` HTTP header using this
>   format. Examples: `it`, `de-at`, `es`, `pt-br`.

Comment: I believe in both cases they correspond to the `Accept-language` HTTP header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language